# how to generate a bi-weekly column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I was asked to aggregate my data by two-week, let's say my data starts at jun 1st 2020, which happens to be a MONDAY. Ever since then, i need to aggregate that by every two-weeks.
I will show you by a simple dataset down below,

```
+----+-----------+----------+
|  id|day_revenue| ts_string|
+----+-----------+----------+
|   1|         10|2020-06-01|
|   1|          8|2020-06-04|
|   2|         10|2020-06-30|
|1081|        100|2020-07-07|
+----+-----------+----------+
```

i skip a lot data, and that is only a sample.

My purpose is making this dataframe looks like the one down below.

```
+----+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
|id  |day_revenue|ts_string |bi_week_start|bi_week_full         |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
|1   |10         |2020-06-01|2020-06-01   |2020-06-01/2020-06-14|
|1   |8          |2020-06-04|2020-06-01   |2020-06-01/2020-06-14|
|2   |10         |2020-06-30|2020-06-29   |2020-06-29/2020-07-12|
|1081|100        |2020-07-07|2020-06-29   |2020-06-29/2020-07-12|
+----+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

so， whatever you do, the 2020-06-01 is a magic day, because we split every two weeks base d on this day. Importantly,bi-week-full column is not necessary but if you can create new column in that way, that will be much more convenient for me.

There are two things please keep in mind,

1. My data frame is still growing every single day.Thus, I would like to find a universal function or general way to treat this kind of ad-hoc request.
2. My data starts from 2020-06-01 and it has accumulated more than two years. It is a big data frame.

THANK YOU in advance.

you can create sample df by code below,

```
data_ls = [('1', '10', '2020-06-01'),
('1', '8', '2020-06-04'),
('2', '10', '2020-06-30'),
('1081', '100', '2020-07-07'),]
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'day_revenue', 'ts_string'])
```

Comment: The last date in the example should be year 2020, not 2022, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `datediff()` and `date_add()`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
(
    df
    .withColumn('start', F.lit('2020-06-01'))
    .withColumn('n', F.floor(F.datediff('ts_string', 'start') / 14).cast('int'))
    .select(
        'id', 'day_revenue', 'ts_string',
        F.date_add('start', F.col('n') * 14).alias('bi_week_start'),
        F.date_add('start', (F.col('n') + 1) * 14 - 1).alias('bi_week_end'),
    )
    .withColumn('bi_week_full', F.concat_ws('/', 'bi_week_start', 'bi_week_end'))
    .show(truncate=False)
)
```